# CVDisplayLink debug messages

Tags: xcode

Since Xcode 13.2.1 I get flooded with CVDisplayLink debug / warning messages.

Like

```
CVDisplayLink::start
CVDisplayLink::stop
```

20 times a second or so.

I think they may come from an WebView which runs an embedded version of the Ace editor.

Does anybody know how to prevent the CVDisplayLink messages specifically ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately disabling OS_ACTIVITY_MODE disables all system logs output including os_log(..)

I found a better solution:

```
CFPreferencesSetValue("cv_note" as CFString, 0 as CFPropertyList, "com.apple.corevideo" as CFString, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost)
CFPreferencesSynchronize("com.apple.corevideo" as CFString, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost)
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to disable the messages is to execute the following command in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.corevideo cv_note 0
```

(Credits for figuring out the keys go to Alexey Martemyanov's answer!)

Answer (score 3):

I get these messages too and also think it has to do with `WKWebview`.

My only workaround for now is trying to silence them with: `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` = `disable` on the Scheme.

#### 1

On Xcode go to `Product` > `Scheme` > `Edit Scheme`

#### 2

On `Run` > `Arguments` add the Environment Variable:

`OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and set the Value to `disable`

[image: Editing the scheme to add environment variable]

These debug messages should not be there next time you run the app.